# How to send ajax request from jquery fullcalendar events

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, fullcalendar

I have got events from database using an ajax and bind those with jquery fullcalendar. The problem is the ajax returns all the events and binds those in the calendar. I have more than 10 thousands of events and the binding takes some time. I need a way to use the arrow button of that calendar and fetch data for the selected view of calendar. So, basically I will fetch data for every click of arrow button and bind those with the calendar.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function showModal() {
        window.location.href("fTrainingSchedule.aspx");
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "calendar.aspx/GetEvents",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function (data) {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'year,month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            defaultDate: new Date(),
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            eventClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {
                window.location.href = "fTrainingSchedule.aspx?id=" + date.scheduleId;
            },
            events: JSON.parse(data.d)
        });
    });
});
```

url: "calendar.aspx/GetEvents"

This gets all the events. I need to get events for every view of calendar date. I will pass parameter with this "GetEvents" method and the parameters will the calendar view's first date and last date.

Comment: Check datesRender event https://fullcalendar.io/docs/datesRender it has View object parameter which has activeStart and activeEnd properties.

Comment: How do I use this with my code here? The ajax should be invoked in every event of fullcalendar. Can you give some elaborate explanation please?

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-function is the solution to this. Use the start and end dates provided by the callback to tell your server to limit the events returned. fullCalendar will automatically request more events from the server if the user moves to different dates